# Understanding forecast accuracy MAPE, WMAPE,WAPE?

Tags: forecasting

I am new to the forecast space and I am trying to understand the different forecast accuracy measures. I am referring to the below link
https://www.otexts.org/fpp/2/5

Can anyone please help me understand the below things:
1. MAPE: I am trying to understand the disadvantage of MAPE "They also have the disadvantage that they put a heavier penalty on negative errors than on positive errors. " Can anyone please provide an example to explain this in detail?
2. Also, I was assuming that WMAPE and WAPE are same. I saw this post at stackoverflow which formulates them differently. 
[What's the gaps for the forecast error metrics: MAPE and WMAPE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994929/whats-the-gaps-for-the-forecast-error-metrics-mape-and-wmape)

Also, can you please help me understand how the weights are calculated? My understanding is higher the value more important it is. But I am not sure how the value is calculated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

MAPE = 100* mean(|(Actual-forecast)/Actual|)

If you check the website https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/smape/ and the example given u will notice that the denominator taken is the forecast which is incorrect (Should be the actual value). With this formula you can see that MAPE does not put a heavier penalty on negative errors than on positive errors.

WMAPE applies weights which may in fact be biased towards the error which would make the metric worse. The weightage for WMAPE is as far as I know based on the use case. For example you are trying to predict the loss but the percentage of loss needs to be weighted with volume of sales because a loss on a huge sale needs better prediction.

In cases where values to be predicted is very low MAD/Mean (a.k.a WAPE) should be used. For example if the sales is 3 units in one particular week (maybe a holiday) and the predicted value is 9 then the MAPE would be 200%. This would bloat up the total MAPE when you look at multiple weeks of data.

The link given below has details of some other stats used for error measurement
http://www.forecastpro.com/Trends/forecasting101August2011.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about the rest, but I came across an answer for the first question recently. 
Check out this website - http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/smape/

The example given there is presented below -

"Armstrong and Collopy (1992) argued that the MAPE "puts a heavier penalty on forecasts that exceed the actual than those that are less than the actual". Makridakis (1993) took up the argument saying that "equal errors above the actual value result in a greater APE than those below the actual value". He provided an example where yt=150 and y^t=100, so that the relative error is 50/150=0.33, in contrast to the situation where yt=100 and y^t=150, when the relative error would be 50/100=0.50."

- y^t == estimated value of y

Answer (score 0):

WMAPE and MAPE are different measures.

MAPE is Mean Absolute Percent Error - this just averages the percent errors.

WMAPE is Weighted Mean Absolute Percent Error = This weights the errors by Volume so this is more rigorous and reliable.

Negative errors do not influence the calculation is this is all absolute error.  This could result from the denominator used which is a separate debate.

You can download a detailed presentation from our website at https://valuechainplanning.com/download/24.  The PDF can be downloaded at https://valuechainplanning.com/upload/details/Forecast_Accuracy_Presentation.pdf.